# How to use variable id as selector in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a fiddle for a selectbox here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5Eebm/ that works nicely but i need to have a dynamic # of selectboxes which means a dynamic # of ids. Being brand new to jQuery and javascript, how would I go about creating a variable selector in the jq if, for instance I were to use a dynamic [idx] value in my php to increment each id by 1 (e.g.: prophlist_1, choose_1; prophlist_2, choose_2; etc). Any insight at all would be very appreciated.

here's the fiddle code:

```
<ul id="prophlist" style="display:none;">
<li>Prophecy 1 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 2 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 3 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 4 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 5 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 6 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 7 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 8 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 9 text</li>
<li>Prophecy 10 text</li>
</ul>
<select id="choose">
<option value="1">Title 1</option>
<option value="2">Title 2</option>
<option value="3">Title 3</option>
<option value="4">Title 4</option>
<option value="5">Title 5</option>
<option value="6">Title 6</option>
<option value="7">Title 7</option>
<option value="8">Title 8</option>
<option value="9">Title 9</option>
<option value="10">Title 10</option>
</select>

<div id="update">
</div>

$('#choose').change(
function(){
    var i = this.selectedIndex;
    $('#update').text($('#prophlist li').eq(i).text());
});
```

Comment: It'd be nice if the title of the question was to be reworded to reflect the question requirement, not the suggested solution.

Answer (score 2):

> **I need to have a dynamic # of select boxes which means a dynamic # of ids**

No. You don't need to use element ids at all to get this functionality working. You can instead give the select elements the same *class*:

```
<select class="choose">
```

And then use that class to bind the same change handler to all of them:

```
$(".choose").change(function() { ... });
```

And then within the handler rather than using an id to find the related div, use [DOM navigation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) like `.next()` to find the div based on its relative position in the markup:

```
    $(this).next().text(...)
```

Also, if the `display:none;` ul element is there solely to hold the descriptions, why don't you get rid of it and add the descriptions directly to each option like this:

```
<option value="1" data-desc="Prophecy text 1">Title 1</option>
```

Putting that together your function might look like this:

```
$('.choose').change(function(){
    $(this).next().text( $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-desc') );
})
```

Here's an updated version of your fiddle that shows that one little bit of JS handling multiple select elements: http://jsfiddle.net/5Eebm/75/

Comment: Thanks. We're almost there... I don't want to display the value of the option  description in the div, i'd like to display the value of the li. see here (http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5Eebm/) how the option text "Title 1" brings up the li text "Prophecy 1 text"...